# Нагрузочное тестирование: "Connection refused” (nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, тестирование, highload, яндекс-танк

Провожу нагрузочное тестирование своего API ЯндексТанком.

Нагрузка: 100RPS в течении 60 секунд POST request с небольшим телом

Не пойму, что происходит: примерно на первые 1600-1900 запросов получаю успешный ответ с кодом `200`. Остальные запросы - ошибка `111 Connection refused`.

Если сразу после первого прогона запустить тест ещё раз, с первого запроса полетят ошибки `111 Connection refused`, а если после запуска подождать 10 минут, то ситуация будет как в начале: 1600-1900 успешных и затем только `111 Connection refused`.

Если же нагрузку уменьшить до  30RPS и продлить тест до 100 секунд. То Ситуация повториться, снова всё сломается после 1600-1900 запросов.

Ощущение, что где-то есть какой-то лимит на количество и на время жизни "чего-то". 
Буду рад любым предложениям, как это можно поправить! Какие параметры подкрутить или куда посмотреть?

Игрался с разными параметрами: worker_processes, worker_rlimit_nofile, worker_connections, keepalive_timeout. Последняя оставшаяся конфигурация приведена ниже. Пока ничего не помогло.

**ulimit -n** `200000`

**Enviroment:** Ubuntu 18.04.1, DigitalOcean: RAM 2Gb + 2CPU

**Nginx config**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log debug;

worker_rlimit_nofile 33000;

events {
    worker_connections  4000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    reset_timedout_connection on;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    include '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*';
}
```

File (server + location)

```
...
    location ~ ^/api {
        content_by_lua '
            ngx.say("OK")
            return ngx.exit(200)
        ';
    }
...
```

**YandexTank Ammo**

```
[Host: myserver.com]
[Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
80 /api
xxxxxx=777777777&yyyyyyy=666666666&zzzzzzzz=ce96c7c3-87e5-4b90-b1e5-9664697aa5b6
```

Comment: А в логах что?..

Comment: ни в error.log, ни в access.log нет никаких строчек о реквестах, даже с уровнем debug

Comment: Если в логах ничего нет, То тут всего 2 варианта: вы смотрите не те логи или танк обращается не к тому сайту

Comment: Логи есть про первые реквесты, а как только число запросов достигает 1600-1900 и начинаются сплошные `Connection refused` - вот тогда логи уже ничего нового не показывают, как будто после 1900 запросов больше нет обращений

Comment: Я бы написал вопрос в службу поддержки DigitalOcean - нет ли у них лимитов на трафик. У меня, например, в одном хостинге вежливо спросили: "Какого хрена моя машина рассылает так дохрена пакетов? Что это я в ней делаю?". Подозреваю, что в DigitalOcean менее вежливые люди, и просто рубят линк.

Comment: GET запросы удаётся слать с частотой 100RPS бесконечно долго. Не похоже, что DigitalOcean что-то режет. Да и в переписке они отрицают наличие каких-либо лимитов со своей стороны

Comment: `вот тогда логи уже ничего нового не показывают, как будто после 1900 запросов больше нет обращений` - подозреваю, что таки не доходят запросики, иначе трудно объяснить, что в лог ничего не пишется. `просто рубят линк` - а давайте вот это и проверим. В танке можно посмотреть кто отдал 111 - Nginx или еще кто-то? Добавьте свой какой-нибудь заголовок аля `X-server: nginx` и даже когда будут проблемы - посмотрите курлом на его наличие в момент "сыпятся 111" .

Comment: Подозреваю, что заголовок не проставится по тем же причинам, по которым и access лог перестаёт писаться: до этого просто дело не дойдёт из гипотез остаётся:
1 - DigitalOcean режет;    
2 - OS, какие-то лимиты;   
3 - Nginx, какие-то лимиты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в моем домашнем роутере

Он попросту не мог справиться с такой нагрузкой

Проблема была решена путем замены роутера